# Execute Newman (Postman) job via Jenkins (output issue)

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

im using windows 10 and configured my Jenkins to perform build for Postman (Newman) collection i received Finished: SUCCESS but in the console for that build i see gibberish data instead of Newman table results:

Started by user admin
Building in workspace C:\Users\amir.jenkins\workspace\Newman
[Newman] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\amir\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins131434029649012710.bat

C:\Users\amir.jenkins\workspace\Newman>cd C:\Users\amir\node_modules\newman\bin

C:\Users\amir\node_modules\newman\bin>node newman -c "C:\Users\amir\Documents\Postman Collections\Test.postman_collection.json" 
newman: the v2.x CLI options are deprecated. You should use newman run  [options] instead.
        refer https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/MIGRATION.md for details.
newman

Test

â†’ getProjectAlerts copy
  POST https://openweathermap.org/apii [200 OK, 91.8KB, 1610ms]
  âˆš  Status code is 200
  âˆš  Body matches string

â”Œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”�
â”‚                         â”‚ executed â”‚   failed â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚              iterations â”‚        1 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚                requests â”‚        1 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚            test-scripts â”‚        1 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚      prerequest-scripts â”‚        0 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚              assertions â”‚        2 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”´â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”´â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ total run duration: 1970ms                    â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ total data received: 91.19KB (approx)         â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ average response time: 1610ms                 â”‚
â””â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”˜

C:\Users\amir\node_modules\newman\bin>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried the option --disable-unicode in your newman command ? can you show in a clear way your newman command and options, please ?

Comment: Below is my Jenkins execute windows batch command for that build : cd C:\Users\amir\node_modules\newman\bin

node newman -c "C:\\Users\\amir\\Documents\\Postman Collections\\Test.postman_collection.json"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not use it with Jenkins but, obviously, you're missing some parameters. Have a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options) for newman options you could use.

First you should do `newman run -c "C:\\Users\\amir\\Documents\\Postman Collections\\Test.postman_collection.json"` and if you still have strange characters issue, try the -disable-unicode option

Comment: newman run --disable-unicode "C:\\Users\\amir\\Documents\\Postman Collections\\Test.postman_collection.json"   and now everything works perfect :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: my pleasure. Glad it helped  :)

Comment: Saved me a lott of effort. Thanks for the solution